# Why before $e^{x}$,the solution was not possible?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

we know the important role of exponential function in solving of ordinary differential equation.But the solution can be done by using  another function like $10^x$ or $2^x$.The example below shows this
If we have $$y''-4y'+3y=0$$
assume the $y=10^{mx}$

$y'=m10^{mx}log(10)$

$y''=m^210^{mx}log^2(10)$
substitute these in the O.D.E to get

$10^{mx}log^2(10)-4(10^{mx}log(10))+3(10^{mx})=0$

$m^210^{mx}log^2(10)-4(m10^{mx}log(10))+3(10^{mx})=0$

$m^2log^2(10)-4mlog(10)+3=0$
The characteristics equation can be solved to get the roots.

We see that the solution of differential equation can be by using $y=10^{mx}$

So Why before this not possible and why the solution must be by using $y=e^{mx}$

Comment: Using $e^{mx}$ instead of $10^{nx}$ is mostly done to avoid all those pesky $\ln(10)$ coefficients you keep getting.

Comment: Note that $e^{mx}=10^{mx/\log (10)}$, so this is really the same technique.  I works fine, as you have shown, but puts a lot of $\log (10)$'s around.  If you were clever enough to guess the right base to use you might even get a cleaner solution.  Why do you say it is not possible?

Comment: @RossMillikan Im with you but I said the solution was not possible because I wrote a book said the solution before $e^x$ was not possible and I want to know why not possible.

Comment: yes yes Im sorry

Comment: what is the book? If not in English, what is the closest translation of the title you can make?

Comment: now, I don't remember the title of book,but I will search about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't give the full quote of what you read, but I suspect the author is not distinguishing between $e^x$ and $10^x$.  What you need to solve these problems is an exponential function that is defined on the reals.  Long ago you could imagine $10^x$ as a $1$ followed by $x$ zeros, but that only works if $x$ is a natural number.  If you extend $10^x$ to real $x$ it will let you solve the problem as you have shown.  I'm not sure it is easy to do the extension without going through $e$, natural logs, Taylor series, etc. so in that sense you can't solve the problem without $e^x$.  Certainly all those $\log (10)$'s in your solution mean you know something about $e$.

Answer (score 2):

Some of the relevant history is discussed in [The Number e](http://www-history.mcs.st-andrews.ac.uk/HistTopics/e.html).  It seems the curves $y = k a^x$ were discussed by Huygens in 1661, somewhat before the number $e$ itself was actually defined (and also before the concept of differential equations).

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible to solve the equations with $10^{mx}$ as you've shown.  However, you'll notice the many appearances of $\log 10$ in the answer.  This does not happen when $e^{mx}$ is used.  So, $e^{mx}$ is used, because it gives us the simplest answers.

Comment: But I know the solution was not possible up to the function #e^x$ come

Comment: I don't understand your comment.

Comment: I mean the solution was not possible by using the $10^{mx}$

Comment: Clearly it was always possible as you proved.